# How to get an ordered list detail using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have questionnaire class with its detail, question, and question group. The structure is like this:

[image]

I create the details view to display a `Questionnaire` and the details. The details should be displayed based on `Sequence` in `QuestionGroup`. Using LINQ, how to get a questionnaire with its details ordered by sequence in question group.

So far, when I create a LINQ syntax to get solve this:

```
var questionnaire = db.Questionnaires
   .Include(q => q.QuestionnaireDetails)
   .FirstOrDefault(q => q.QuestionnaireID == questionnaireID);
```

I've got 2 problems:

1) I cannot call `Include` for `Question` and `QuestionGroup` (eager loading) 
   `.Include(q => q.QuestionnaireDetails.Question)` <-- error

Error: 
`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

2) I cannot call `OrderBy` by `Sequence`, before call `.FirstOrDefault()` I added 
  `.OrderBy(q => q.QuestionnaireDetails.Question.QuestionGroup.Sequence)` <-- error

Error: 
`'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MvcApplication1.Models.QuestionnaireDetail>' does not contain a definition for 'Question' and no extension method 'Question' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MvcApplication1.Models.QuestionnaireDetail>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**UPDATE**

I tried solution from @JesseJames, with a little modification:

```
var questionnaire = from qg in db.QuestionGroups
                    join q in db.Questions on qg.QuestionGroupID equals q.QuestionGroupID
                    join qd in db.QuestionnaireDetails on q.QuestionID equals qd.QuestionID
                    join qe in db.Questionnaires on qd.QuestionnaireID equals qe.QuestionnaireID
                    orderby qg.Sequence
                    select new Questionnaire { 
                        QuestionnaireID = qe.QuestionnaireID, 
                        Date = qe.Date,
                        Respondent = qe.Respondent,
                        QuestionnaireDetails = qe.QuestionnaireDetails };
```

but I've got error:

`The entity or complex type 'MvcApplication1Model.Questionnaire' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I'm using EF 6 and ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Does `db.Questionnaires` return an IEnumerable, IQueryable or ObjectQuery?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it returns `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Questionnaire>`

Comment: Alright.  What is the exact wording of the error messages you are getting?  (include them in your question).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I've added the error on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67284/discussion-between-willy-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from qg in db.QuestionGroup
            from q in db.Questions.Where(r=>r.QuestionGroupId == qg.QuestionGroupId)
            from qd in db.QuestionnaireDetail.WHere(r=>r.QuestionId== q.QuestionId)
            from qe in db.Questionnaire.Where(r=>r.QuestinnareId == qd.QuestinnareId)
            orderby qg.Sequence
            select new { Questionnaire = q, QuestionnaireDetail = qd };
```

**EDIT**

You may prefer this syntax

```
var query = from qg in db.QuestionGroup
            join q in db.Questions on qg.QuestionGroupId equals q.QuestionGroupId
            join qd in db.QuestionnaireDetail on q.QuestionId equals qg.QuestionId
            join qe in db.Questionnaire on qd.QuestinnareId equals qe.QuestinnareId
            orderby qg.Sequence
            select new { Questionnaire = q, QuestionnaireDetail = qd };
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, but so many 'from' here, I've never seen it before. Is it the only way or could we use `Include` rather than use many 'from'?

Comment: using `from` is similar to `INNER JOIN` in SQL. Look at my edit

Comment: I've got error `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`. I'm using AutoMapper, after get questionnaire from database, I mapped to viewmodel `QuestionnaireViewModel questionnaireVM = Mapper.Map<QuestionnaireViewModel>(questionnaire);`

Comment: What type is you `questionnaire` variable? Automapper doesnt know how to map `questionnaire` to QuestionnaireViewModel.

Comment: It's `Questionnaire` model, in my question, I'm using `FirstOrDefault()` to return it to `Questionnaire` type. But I've got the problem when `Include` `Question` and `QuestionGroup` (for eager loading) and sort the `QuestionnaireDetails` by `Sequence` in `QuestionGroup`

Comment: I'm working with EF in production and I've never seen `Include` statement... Just use LINQ to fetch data. When writing LINQ query imagine that use pure T-SQL. First - create a class that will represent query result row. Then fetch data: `select new ResultRowClass { QuestionId = q.Id, RespondentName = qe.Respondent  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67290/discussion-between-willy-and-jessejames).